# AWS ELB Server certificate trust

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssl-certificate

**Background:**

I have an IIS application running behind a AWS ELB. The SSL certificate is presented by the server and not the ELB [TCP pass threw].

**Question:**

Does the ELB have to trust the Certificate presented by IIS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The SSL certificate is presented by the server and not the ELB [TCP pass threw].

If you are using TCP pass through, then no, it doesn't matter what the certificate looks like. The ELB is just forwarding the raw TCP data. When using TCP->TCP the ELB doesn't really even know that the traffic is SSL.